# How can i explain this line of syntax

Tags: python

I am learning python and have a very simple query

Basically  what exactly does this code below mean in english

```
for i in values : 
   for x in othervalues :
```

does it mean compare all values in values to all values in othervalues ?

Comment: Go through `values` using `i` to represent each value. Each time, go through `othervalues` using `x` to represent each othervalue. It doesn't say anything about comparing things.

Comment: Are you hiding a third line under the second `for` from us?

Comment: yeah there would be an if as third line but i just wanted to know was there actual any comarison done in the above lines.

Comment: no, no comparison involved. Those two `for` loops iterate on the given sequences. The `StopIteration` exception is raised when the end of a sequence is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khelwood said, it simply iterates on two loops.

It iterates through the values in `values`, assigning each value to the variable `i`

Inside such loop it does the same thing, iterating on the values of `othervalues` and assigning each value to the variable `x`

You can verify it simply adding a print statement inside the loop, that shows the values of `i` and `x`

```
for i in values : 
    for x in othervalues :
        print('i={}, x={}'.format(i,x))
```

e.g. with an input of

```
values = 'abc'
othervalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

it produces

```
i=a, x=1
i=a, x=2
i=a, x=3
i=a, x=4
i=a, x=5
i=b, x=1
i=b, x=2
i=b, x=3
i=b, x=4
i=b, x=5
i=c, x=1
i=c, x=2
i=c, x=3
i=c, x=4
i=c, x=5
```

Please make sure you understand how iteration works in python, reading the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)
and [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols)
and more tutorials you can find on the internet.